# Scalar spherical wave in terms of Cylindrical coordinates

Tags: scattering

[image]I am looking at a problem where a scalar spherical wave is scattered by an uncharged cylinder. I want to work in cylindrical coordinates in order to simplify it. Can anyone tell me how to expand the scalar spherical wave in cylindrical coordinates (probably using modified Bessel functions) ?

The source can either be on the x, y, or z- axis, outside the cylinder, as shown in the figure.

Comment: Could you describe the problem in a little more detail? Where is the source of the spherical wave relative to the cylinder? (A diagram would certainly help, but even a description in words should suffice).

Comment: @ApproximatelyTrue : The post is edited as per your suggestion.